# How to get IMEI number in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, numbers, imei

I'm developing a PhoneGap Android mobile application using jQuery, JavaScript and HTML. I want to get the mobile IMEI. I have tried this code from this [Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html).

I am getting the number like this: **97734a345d234d**.
I have checked my device to get IMEI number using `*#06#`.
I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: To confirm your IMEI, it's usually printed under the battery or somewhere hidden (and on the box it came in if that's available).

Comment: @StackOverflowed As you correctly pointed out, it is usually printed **under** the battery, so to read it, it is required to turn off the device and remove the battery. Using `*#06#` quick code, metioned by OP is way, way faster and easier. Doesn't require powering off the device.

Comment: @StackOverflowed would be super helpful if you could provide some code to programmatically remove the battery and read the printed IMEI.

Comment: lol @ both you wise asses, including @CodeBling. Part of his question was: "I dunno whether it is correct or wrong". I was just saying how he could confirm whether the number he was getting from *#06# was accurate.

Comment: @StackOverflowed haha ok, I think he meant that he wasn't sure if the hex number is correct - looks to me like it could be valid if converted to decimal.  *#06# is a well-known way to obtain the IMEI on most phones

Answer (score 5):

Fetch the IMEI number in the class which extends DroidGap class and save the value of imei number in static member and then access this static field from where ever you want... example code is here

```
public class MyApp extends DroidGap
{
    private static String imei; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei=tm.getDeviceId();
    }
    static public String getIMEI(){
        return imei;
    }
}
// where ever u need imei number use this code

String imei=MyApp.getIMEI();
```

Comment: **Brilliant** example! Pitty, that I can give you only +1. Thanks!

Comment: @bschandramohan you need to create a plugin that invoke some native code (PhoneGap) via JS, see this link: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/03/01/pushing-data-to-a-phonegap-web-view/

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access the IMEI via html or JavaScript. But you can write an app which reads the IMEI for you.

Just call [getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29). Don't forget that you need the [READ_PHONE_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) permission in your manifest.

Comment: I have i tried this getDeviceId().But am getting the error as network status 1=Reference error :can't find a variable getDeviceId

Comment: @Priya The linked function `getDeviceId()` returns a string. Do you wrote a Android App? Also note this: `You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, you retrieve a reference to an instance through Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).`

Answer (score 4):

You could write a phonegap plugin to return you the IMEI number. As the phonegap doesnt return imei for Android devices, it returns an random 64-bit number.

Here is a complete plugin to get the real IMEI number in a phonegap application (please note that this plugin is not "plugmanable" but if follow the instructions it will work. I have tested on phonegap 2.9. I am planning on writing a real "plugmanable" plugin with a few device information for phonegap 3.0).

Here is the java class for that extends from CordovaPlugin (**DeviceInfo.java**):

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class DeviceInfo extends CordovaPlugin {

    public DeviceInfo(){
    }

    public String DeviceImeiNumber(){
        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);            
        return tManager.getDeviceId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (action.equals("imeiNumber")) {
            callbackContext.success(this.DeviceImeiNumber());
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

And then you need a js object so you can access your plugin on the other side (deviceinfo.js):

```
(function( cordova ) {

    function DeviceInfo() {}

    DeviceInfo.prototype.imeiNumber = function(win, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(
                function (args) { if(win !== undefined) { win(args); } },
                function (args) { if(fail !== undefined) { fail(args); } },
                "DeviceInfo", "imeiNumber", []);
    };

    if(!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }

    if (!window.plugins.DeviceInfo) {
        window.plugins.DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();
    }

})( window.cordova );
```

Add your plugin on res/xml/config.xml file inside your project like this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="DeviceInfo" value="com.XXX.XXXXX.DeviceInfo"/>
</plugins>
```

And add the READ_PHONE_STATE permission inside your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

After this you need to add you deviceinfo.js file into your page, and after the **deviceready** you can use your plugin like this:

```
plugins.DeviceInfo.imeiNumber(function(imei){
   console.log("imei "+ imei);                   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would only be possible if you exploit some other apps logging of the IMEI and I'm not sure if any do.

Assuming some do, ideally a system app, you can read the logs and parse them for that information.

Good luck, post back with successes/failures

Comment: `getDeviceId()` is a great option too, if it will work with phonegap

Comment: I have i tried this getDeviceId().But am getting the error as network status 1=Reference error :can't find a variable getDeviceId

Comment: Then I think your only bet is to somehow achieve it how I described in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You're pointing to [PhoneGap Tutorial version 1.0.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html). It is very old and it lacs a lot of information. If you, for example, read the very same page for [version 2.1.0 of PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html) you'll notice a comment made for [device.uuid Quick Example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid), where it is said, that `device.uuid` returns IMEI number **only in case of Tizen platform**. All other platforms, including Android, you mentioned, does return *something else*.

You can't get device's IMEI in pure HTML / Javascript (application compiled through PhoneGap Build). To read it, you have to build locally, for Android platform only and include some native plugin that will do the job for you -- for example something like [this one](http://austinejei.blogspot.com/2013/05/phonegap-plugin-for-imei.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *"Device" object* from Phonegap. Since **"device"** is assigned to the window object, it is implicitly in the global scope so you can easily call it in your onDeviceReady function eg:

```
var deviceID = device.uuid
```

Please note that on Android it returns a random 64-bit integer as a string. The integer is generated on the device's first boot. On BlackBerry it returns the PIN number of the device. This is a nine-digit unique integer as a string and on iPhone it returns a string of hash values created from multiple hardware identifies.It is guaranteed to be unique for every device and cannot be tied to the user account.

See the full example [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid)

Answer (score 0):

You may change getUuid function defined in platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java in this way

```
public String getUuid() {
    //String uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)this.cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
    return uuid;
}
```

just comment the first line and add the two new ones.

You also have to add

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plugin called `cordova-plugin-imeigetter` for cordova (only for Android devices) that does what you want. I hope it helps you.

---

**Installation:**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-imeigetter.git
```

---

**Usage:**

This plugin exports an object with one method called `get`:

```
window.plugins.imeiGetter.get(function(imei){
   console.log(imei);
});
```

---

**GitHub:** https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-imeigetter