# How can we retrieve mobile phone number & IMEI details using IBM Worklight?

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, phone-number, imei

Are there API's available in Worklight so that we can retrieve mobile phone number & IMEI details using IBM Worklight ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a Cordova plug-in. [Read the training materials for this purpose](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova).

Your plug-in can be based on this code, or similar: [How to get IMEI number in PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742850/how-to-get-imei-number-in-phonegap)