# How to get IMEI in ionic2 on an android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to obtain the imei of an android device in ionic 2, but so far no luck.

In ionic 1 l just used an ngCordova plugin like cordova-uid https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid.

Is there a plugin for ionic-native that I can use to obtain the imei or is there any other way to get the imei.

Answer (score 1):

Can use this code.

> cordova plugin add org.hygieiasoft.cordova.uid

Or

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid

For test use console.log

```
  declare var cordova: any;

  export class MyApp {

  constructor(platform: Platform ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
       console.log(cordova.plugins.uid.IMEI);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the deviceId in the response is the same as imei. you can do the following

```
Sim.getSimInfo().then(
(info) => { console.log('Sim info: ', info); 
        // the line below give you the imei number 
   console.log(info.deviceId)
 },
(err) => console.log('Unable to get sim info: ', err)
 );

 Sim.hasReadPermission().then(
 (info) => console.log('Has permission:', info)
 );

 Sim.requestReadPermission().then(
      () => console.log('Permission granted'),
      () => console.log('Permission denied')
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this link  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sim

Install plugin via

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sim
```

use code

```
import { Sim } from 'ionic-native';

Sim.getSimInfo().then(
  (info) => console.log('Sim info: ', info),
  (err) => console.log('Unable to get sim info: ', err)
);

Sim.hasReadPermission().then(
  (info) => console.log('Has permission:', info)
);

Sim.requestReadPermission().then(
  () => console.log('Permission granted'),
  () => console.log('Permission denied')
);
```

Comment: How you are getting Device IMEI Number from Sim? Please Help.