# how to get IMEI number in ionic 2 mobile app?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, imei

I am building a mobile application and want to access the IMEI number.

I have gone through the following plugins.

1. https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin
2. https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid
3. https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei

And all of them are giving me 404 error.

Finally I got one plugin that I could install

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/imeiplugin

and below is the code I wrote to access the IMEI

The below code is written inside my home constructor.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
            window["plugins"].imeiplugin.getImei(function (imei) {
                console.log(imei);
            });
        });
```

But the control never goes to the console.log();

Am I doing anything wrong here??

Or if anyone has integrated the IMEI number with some other method please let me know.

Or as per suggested in the below link do I have to build my own custom plugin??

1. [How to get IMEI number in PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742850/how-to-get-imei-number-in-phonegap)

I am stuck here and I am looking for an efficient way any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this plugin works: 
https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid

(Using: cordova plugin add org.hygieiasoft.cordova.uid **returns 404)**

So try this instead:
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid`

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
   alert(cordova.plugins.uid.IMEI);
});
```

Comment: i tried this plugin, but this is also giving me error!!!! says failed to fetch plugin. Can you share your ionic info??

Comment: Please try again, here is the screen shot of the plugin I added.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5NOdnm05pUWRUdtUUVWblBkdVE

Comment: This worked for me: cordova plugin add https://github.com/lionelhe/cordova-plugin-uid.git